# How to exclude files from code coverage using sbt scoverage and scala3

Tags: scala, sbt, scala-3, scoverage, zio-test

I am trying to exclude the files from code coverage to increase the percentage. Scala2 supports this by using the properties coverageExcludedFiles but scala3 doesn't supports this. Is there any alternative solution to exclude the files.

Tried by adding $coverage-off$ and $coverage-on$ for blocks of code which is not working.